# How to display a table from an object returned by functional component that calls fastAPI endpoint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fastapi

I am building a web app that given some user input, does some math, and outputs the profit per hour of each item that can be created by an inputted building.

Here is an example input:

```
Physics laboratory 2 1.0 0.01
```

and output:

```
{
    Energy research: 821.6746356364301, 
    Mining research: 742.7240922619478, 
    Electronics research: 864.3855853308221
}
```

I want to display a table using this data, with columns named like **Item** and **Profit Per Hour**.

I studied [this React Functional Table](https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/zYvEbML) and others that use `.map` to display a table. However, when I tried to copy/paste the example and adapt `useState` to my output example given above, I got errors that each child in the list must have a `Key` or something to that effect.

I have read [lists and keys in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). I feel I should open a new venv and create-react-app to play around with `map` and `keys`.

Is this the correct direction to take to display a table like I intend?

Here is an example of my code showing a functional component that takes input from text fields and calls the api endpoint using them to return an object.

I wonder whether the `async` is potentially causing the `key` errors as maybe the table is trying to be created before the `promise` finishes.

```
const populateTable = async () => {
    try{
        let encodedName = encodeURI(buildingName)
        let targetURI = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/calculateProfitPerHourOf{}?buildingName=${encodedName}&buildingLevel=${buildingLevel}&productionModifierPercentage=${productionModifierPercentage}&administrationCostPercentage=${adminCostPercentage}`
        let res = await axios.get(targetURI);
        let arr = res.data
        setResult(arr);
        console.log(arr)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

const HandleClick = () => {
    populateTable();
}
```

Comment: Yesterday I studied react-tables and thay seems to be the way to go. I restructured the output into nested dictionaties with keys that can be used as accessors and will give that a go and close this question if I get it working. Thanks for the edit PeterJames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used react-tables to accomplish dynamic row data in a table with fixed columns, not without a lot of help and struggle. I first had to restructure my output data into a nested array so that I would have keys that I could use as accessors, this made things easier to read anyways. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523350/invalid-hook-call-react-hook-using-react-table-to-try-and-display-some-mock-jso/73523635?noredirect=1#comment129836215_73523635) for an example and help I got from another.

Comment: Can you please also add relevant code as information to your answer so that other people don't have to follow a link?

Comment: It would practically be a duplicate question and answer at thay point, this question was asking how to go about it and the answer was using react-tables, the other question was a particular problem I had with react-tables and the answer resolved the issue. I will just delete this question

Comment: Just kidding I can't delete it lol I will edit more info in next time including doing stack overflow not on mobile and think about it.